# How to convert HTML CSS class into style in pure python - what kind of library could be used on GAE 

Tags: python, css, google-app-engine, email

Is there any pure python library to use on Google App Engine which allow to convert HTML with CSS class into HTML with styles only for emailing purpose on gmail.

Want to make such conversion on google app engine.

XHTML with CSS class:

```
<p class="xx">xxx</p>
<p class="yy">yyy</p>
```

Considering that CSS is such:

```
p.xx, p.yy { font-size: 120%; }
p.yy { color:red; }
```

I want to convert XHTML classes into styles to remove CSS inclusion as it required by Gmail:

```
<p style="font-size:120%">xx</p>
<p style="font-size:120%;color:red;">yy</p>
```

Is any hint - I could try to code it in regex since CSS is simple but not want to invent the wheel again.

Comment: Can't you include the CSS in a `<style>` tag in the top of the html?

Comment: No, I can not - since it have to be style=".*".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at xhtml2pdf (under Apache License) for the code that combines the HTML and CSS together and then change the output from PDF to HTML.

Comment: Is is pure python - since it need to be used on Google App Engine it important? Whatever it nice idea to use PDF since it looks same in e-mail-s I am currently target HTML since it need some more interaction but for advertisement could nice solution.